# Navigate Url with data binding

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to have a hyperlink binded with the product name and navigate to product details page according to id. The navigate url is always with product id 0. Here is my code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink 
            ID="hl1" 
            Text='<%# Bind("Product_name") %>' 
            runat="server"
            DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductId" 
            ControlStyle-ForeColor="#0066FF" 
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId{0}"
            NavigateUrl="~/ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId{0}" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use like this--

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ProductId","~/ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId{0}" ) %>'
```